# JDK Flight Recorder on CI/CD Plattform

Tags: continuous-integration, jfr

I am currently using JDK Flight Recorder with JDK 11 and came across some trouble in the CI/CD Plattform. Unfortunately, there is not too much documentation on the new Flight Recorder, but rather on the older one, which was still developed under Java.
When I try to start tests directly from the IDE, everything works fine and I get my recording files.
When I try to do the same thing, automatically, in the CI/CD Plattform, it causes time out and a lot of different indefinite failures, among them: trouble creating the file, the file is not even written, etc.

The JVM commands I used are the following (I put extra spaces for better readability):

- `-XX:+FlightRecorder`
- `-XX:StartFlightRecording= name="UiTestServer", settings="profile", dumponexit=true, filename=""+System.getenv("CI_PROJECT_DIR") + "flightRecording/javaFlightRecorder.jfr"`

The commands are the same that the IDE uses automatically, when starting the flight recording with right click on the specified test.

Does anybody know, whether the Flight Recorder has problems with such systems or specific services which might run parallely to it? I heard of some profiling tools, that are unable to perform on CI Plattforms.

If you need more detail, just ask me. Though, it might happen that I cannot tell anything related to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late as an answer, but JFR can definitely run in CI/CD environments. I have successfully attached JFR to our [JMH](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh) microbenchmarks and published the results as artifacts in Atlassian Bamboo. Our Bamboo agents are running on AWS, so JFR itself should be good for most cloud environments.

Answer (score 0):

JFR has been built to work in production systems, but if you want guarantees of low overhead (<1%), you should use the default settings, not profile.

'profile' is for a shorter period of time, i.e. 10 minutes, where it may be OK with additional overhead to gain more insight.

This is what I would recommend, for JDK 11 and later:

```
$ java -XX:StartFlightRecording:filename=/path
```

- There is no need set dumponexit=true if a filename has been specified.
- -XX:+FlightRecorder is only  needed before JDK 8u40.
- You can set a name if you like, but it's typically not needed. If you want to use jcmd and dump a recording, the name can be omitted.